# Convert mm/dd/yyyy string column to date in csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and trying to get some data analysis done both to learn python programming skills and so i can automate this.
I checked everything here on stackflow and can't find the answer.

i have a simple script sofar:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from datetime import datetime


jde_forecast = "C:\Users\\taerts\Documents\\forecastBU.csv"
cols = ["Short Item No", "2nd Item Number", "3rd Item Number","Bus Unit","Forecast Quantity","Request Date","Business Unit","F T","Short Item No"]

forecast_file = read_csv(jde_forecast,names = cols,index_col=1, dtype={"Request Date":datetime})
forecast_file['Request Date'] = forecast_file['Request Date'].astype(datetime)

forecast = forecast_file.convert_objects(convert_dates=True, convert_numeric=True, convert_timedeltas=True, copy=True)


print forecast.groupby(["Bus Unit","Request Date"])["Forecast Quantity"].sum()
```

problem is the sum i now get is lined up in week intervals but not in the right sequence. this wouldn't be a problem but i need to get to the month of each date in order to do the next step i guess.
 I plan to add up the weeks into 4 week buckets. If you have any suggestions how i can get that step done that would be appreciated aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure on your goal but I am sure it pertains to using datetime.strptime() function. Look at the link provided
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior 
Edit: So I guess you can strip the date. save it to a variable in the format you desire and put it back into where you need to in your CSV cell

Comment: Thing is i cant even get the column to be recognized as datetime. if i do types on it it returns the request date as an object

Comment: end goal is btw to sum up all the quantities per BU per 4 week bucket